# Button and function doesn't work at second window of PyQT5 app

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

In my application I have 2 QMainWindows. The UI file generated with pyuic5 and stored in separate files. When I'm clicked button in MainWindow opens a second window called BlockWindow. In this window in **init** func stored method "loaddata" and its loads the data in QTableWidget. However when you open second window nothing happens. But if you are debug separately file BlockWindow(second window) it works perfectly. Can you suggest what the problem actually is?

MainWindow.py

```
from MainWindowUI import Ui_MainWindow
from BlockWindowUI import Ui_BlockWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.loaddata)
        self.ui.action.triggered.connect(self.openJournal)
        self.ui.action_4.triggered.connect(exit)
        self.ui.label_2 = QLabel('<h1 style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></h1>')
        self.loaddata()

   def loaddata(self):
        conn = pyodbc.connect(
            "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-49J58F3\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Plan;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
        query = "SELECT nn, name, metering, volume, date_end, responsible, txt_name from dbo.Card_plan"
        result = conn.execute(query).fetchall()
        self.ui.tableWidget.clearSelection()
        self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        conn.commit()

    def openJournal(self):
        self.BlockWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_BlockWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.BlockWindow)
        self.BlockWindow.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

BlockWindow.py

```
from BlockWindowUI import *

class BlockWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_BlockWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BlockWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_BlockWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.dels)
        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(BlockWindow.close)
        self.ui.label_2 = QLabel('<h1 style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></h1>')
        self.loaddata()

    def loaddata(self):
        conn = pyodbc.connect(
            "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-49J58F3\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Plan;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
        query = "SELECT * from dbo.Block"
        result = conn.execute(query).fetchall()
        self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: I suppose your error is in this line `self.BlockWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()`. You are never actually using your custom class but the default one.

Comment: @mapf ok can you help how I'm actually need to replace this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainWindow` class try changing your `openJournal` method to this:

```py
    def openJournal(self):
        self.BlockWindow = BlockWindow()
        self.BlockWindow.show()
```

And don't forget to import your class to MainWindow.py:

```py
from BlockWindow import BlockWindow
```